# Unable to run another python script in azure function using python

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have created an event grid triggered azure function in python. I have deployed my solution to azure successfully and the execution is working fine. But, I have an issue with calling another python script in the same folder location. My code is given below: -

```
import os, json, subprocess
import logging   
import azure.functions as func

def main(event: func.EventGridEvent):
    try:
        correctionsMessages = event.get_json()
        for correctionMessage in correctionsMessages:
            strMessage = json.dumps(correctionMessage)
            full_path_to_script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + correctionMessage['ScriptName'] + '.py')
            logging.info('Script Path: %s', full_path_to_script)
            logging.info('Parameter: %s', json.dumps(detectionMessage))
            subprocess.check_call('python '+ full_path_to_script + ' ' +  json.dumps(strMessage))

        result = json.dumps({
            'id': event.id,
            'data': event.get_json(),
            'topic': event.topic,
            'subject': event.subject,
            'event_type': event.event_type,
        })
        logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Error: %s', e)
```

The above code is giving error for **subprocess.check_call**. Error is "Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python /home/site/wwwroot/Detections/Script1.py". Script1.py is in same folder with **init**.py. When i am running this function locally, it is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 3):

Per my experience, the error was caused by the `subprocess.check_call` function not know the call path of `python`, not due to the `Script1.py` path.

On your local for Azure Functions development environment, the `python` path has been configured in the local environment variable, so the `subprocess.check_call` function could invoke `python` via search the python execute file from the paths of environment variable. But on cloud, there is not a python path value pre-configured in the same environment variable, only the Azure Function Host know the real absoluted path for Python.

So the solution is to find out the real absoluted path of Python and use it instead of `python` in your code.

However, in Azure Function for Python stack runtime, I think it's not a good idea for using `subprocess.check_call` to spawn a child process to do some processing for a given message. The safe and correct way is to define a function in `Script1.py` or directly in `__init__.py` to pass the given message as parameters to realize the same feature.